# Tangent space of a quadric surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q \subset \mathbb P^3$ a quadric surface. If $L \subset Q$ is a line, I wanted to compute $L^2$ using Chern classes. I know this is zero but I tried twice and failed so I would appreciate any corrections. My mistake probably comes from the computation of $c(TQ)$.

Here is what I did : I have the exact sequence $0 \to TL \to TQ_{|L} \to N_{L/Q} \to 0$ and by definition $\deg N_{L/Q} = L^2$.

By definition, $TL = O_L(2)$ so $c(TL) = 1 + 2p$ where $p \in L$. Now, $Q \cong \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ so I would say that $ TQ = O(2) \oplus O(2)$ so $c(TQ_{|L}) = (1+2p)^2 = 1 + 4p$. So necessary $c(N_{L/Q}) = 1 + 2p$ which is wrong since we should have $L^2 = 0$.

On the other hand, we have the sequence $0 \to TQ \to T\mathbb P^2_{|Q} \to O_Q(2) \to 0$ so we have $TQ = (1+h)^3(1-2h)^{-1} = (1+3h)(1-2h) = 1 - 6h $ where $h$ is an hyperplane section of $Q$. But this still gives me a wrong result, since I should have $c(N_{L/Q}) =(1- 6p)(1-2p) = 1 - 8p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second method is fine! There were just a couple of very minor slips. It looks like you used the Euler sequence and the adjunction formula, to compute $c(T_Q)$. Unfortunately, the answer is $c(T_Q) = (1 + h)^4(1+2h)^{-1}$, rather than $(1+ h)^3(1 - 2h)^{-1}$! Your expression for $c(T_L) = 1 + 2h$ is correct, and this gives $c(N_{L/Q}) = (1 + h)^4(1 + 2h)^{-2} = 1 + 0h$, which is exactly what you want.

In your first method, the statement $T_Q = O(2) \oplus O(2)$ isn't quite right. It should really be $T_Q = O(2,0) \oplus O(0,2)$ (i.e. we need to distinguish between the hyperplane classes coming from the two $\mathbb P^1$ factors in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$). (Note that the hyperplane class of the $\mathbb P^3$ is actually a section of $O(1,1)$ in this notation, whereas $L$ is either a section of $O(1,0)$ or a section of $O(0,1)$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can I ask you a last question ? With your correction I write $T_Q = O(2,0) \oplus O(0,2)$, so I have $c(TQ) = c(O(2,0))c(O(0,2)) = (1+2 \alpha)(1 + 2 \beta) = 1 + 2 \alpha + 2 \beta + 4 \alpha \beta$ where $\alpha = c(O(1,0))$ and $\beta = c(O(0,1))$. And here again $c(N_{L/Q}) = (1 - 2p)(1+ 4p) \neq 1$. What is wrong again ?

Comment: Suppose (without loss of generality) that $L$ is a section of $O(1,0)$, i.e. $L$ looks like ${\rm pt} \times \mathbb P^1 \subset \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \subset \mathbb P^3$. Then, the restriction of $O(1,0)$ to $L$ is the trivial bundle! So $\alpha$ restricted to $L$ is zero! However, the restriction of $O(0,1)$ to $L$ is $O(1)$, and hence, $\beta$ restricted to $L$ is $p$. So $c(N_{L/Q}) = (1-2p)(1+2p) = 1 + 0p$ as required.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot !!